# Databinding Oracle Stored Procedure duplicate columns

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.NET Web Application with a GridView that must display the results (stored in a Hashtable) of a Oracle stored procedure.

At the moment I am databinding the code after the click of a button. The problem is that in fact after every click I am getting duplicate columns.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is actually pretty simple.

Just remove the columns and re-add them.